# Can I mock a dependency to the system under test if it is not a direct dependency?

Tags: java, junit, mockito, spring-test

My question relates to Mockito, JUnit and Spring Test.

Say I have the following graph of dependencies in an application:

```
SystemUnderTest --> Service1 --> Service2 --> ServiceN
```

Can I mock **`ServiceN`** even if it is not a direct dependency of the system under test (`SystemUnderTest`) but rather a transitive dependency (only `Service1` is a direct dependency above)?

All of this, assuming `Service1` and `Service2` are not mocked themselves (except with `spy()`).

Comment: did you give it a try already? post some of your attempts to accomplish this.. it is definately possible

Comment: Hi Maciej, Thanks for your comment. I have not given it a try yet. I was interested to have feedback and general considerations before implementing a sample.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible with the [`MockBean`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/mock/mockito/MockBean.html) annotation.

[Example source:](https://dzone.com/articles/mockbean-spring-boots-missing-ingredient)

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class MockBeanIntegrationTest {
    @MockBean
    private SomeService someService;
    @Before
    public void setupMock() {
        when(someService.getResult())
            .thenReturn("success");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you add more details to your reply please?

Comment: @balteo added an example